# Is there a javascript development environment that runs on a tablet?

Tags: javascript, android

I travel a lot by train, recently bought an android tablet and I would like to learn some javascript. I can read the books on my tablet, but I want to program on it as well. Is there a way to develop on the tablet? The solutions I have seen focus on developing on a PC and run on emulator/tablet, that's not what I want.

Comment: Off topic question. This place is just for coding questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have an Internet connection you can use http://jsfiddle.net for testing snippets of code. You can also select a js framework to work with on the left navigator.

Comment: Thanks! This seems very useful. there no such thing as an environment on the tablet itself? I do not always have internet.